# Get exact Intersection-Point of a Ray and a Sprite

Tags: three.js

I want to get the exact intersection point of a ray and a sprite. But when I do this:

```
var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position ).normalize());
var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(spriteMaterial);

var intersect = ray.intersectObject(sprite);
```

then intersect.point is just the position of the sprite, instead of the exact point that I need.

I need this so I can check if the part of the texture that has been clicked is visible or not. (Alpha value)

Is there a way to get the exact intersection, or is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently supported. See `Raycaster.js` if you want to try to hack your own solution. Sprites can be rotated (turned on their side), so the solution is not trivial.

A reasonable work-around is to create a `Mesh` from a `PlaneGeometry` and set

```
mesh.quaternion = camera.quaternion.
```

three.js r.64

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I'll use planes from now on.